# Kuzzle [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];

Tags: kuzzle

I am having an unusual error suddenly when trying to write documents in my index in Kuzzle

```
[X] Errorindex [&datasensor.config] blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];
```

Everything was working well until today. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error related to the elasticsearch. The index is locked in read-only mode, you can unlock it using the Open Index API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html).

This usually happens when there is not enough space left on the disk (when the disk is filled to 90% of its capacity). So before trying to use the ES API, take a look at your disk status